# To which DBs can I connect via DB LINK, from Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dblink

I'd like to know to which DBs can I connect, via DB Link, from a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 DB?

Is there a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "DB link" you mean a "linked server"? There is no list, because as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) says:

> SQL Server distributed queries are designed to work with any OLE DB
>   provider that implements the required OLE DB interfaces. However, SQL
>   Server has been tested against only the SQL Server Native Client OLE
>   DB Provider and certain other providers.

And:

> OLE DB providers vary greatly in the type and number of parameters
>   required. For example some providers require you to provide a security
>   context for the connection using sp_addlinkedsrvlogin (Transact-SQL).
>   Some OLE DB providers allow SQL Server to update data on the OLE DB
>   source. Others provide only read-only data access. For information
>   about each OLE DB provider, consult documentation for that OLE DB
>   provider.

In other words, you can use any OLE DB provider to create a linked server but configuration and behaviour varies a lot.

MSDN includes a [list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187072%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of tested providers, although there is no SQL Server 2012 version of the page.

Comment: I see... is there an unofficial list of known OLE DB providers to work well?

Comment: There is an official list of tested providers (I've added it to my answer) but I've never seen an unofficial one. And "works well" is a fairly subjective description, e.g. if a specific provider works for my `SELECT` queries but not your `UPDATE` queries then it's fine for me but probably not for you.